# How to quickly render about 30000 records in a dropdown?

Tags: html, performance, drop-down-menu

I have a table in database that contains the employee details. Currently it has around 28K records and it is increasing in its size day by day. I have to fetch all those records and show them in a dropdown menu.

Also, I want to add filter functionality to the dropdown i.e. let the user filter the records by typing in.
I don't know how to do it efficiently, kindly guide me.

I am using PHP and Oracle database. I have tried to render all records using the PHP code but it is very slow.

Following is the code I have tried

```
<select name="alias" id="alias" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here">
    <option value=""></option>
        <?php   
            $query = "SELECT EMPLOYEENAME, EMPLOYEEID FROM EMPLOYEES; 
            $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            oci_execute($stid);
            $nrows = oci_fetch_all($stid,$hr_result);
            for ($i=0; $i<$nrows ; $i++) {
                echo "<option value={$hr_result['EMPLOYEEID'][$i]}>{$hr_result['EMPLOYEENAME'][$i]}</option>"; 
            }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: 30k item in a drop down select field is pretty crazy. One simple solution would be to put a form on the previous webpage where the user could input a name fragment, then use LIKE to select only employee names with that name fragment, e.g. WHERE EMPLOYEENAME LIKE '%$fragment%'. It is good practice to use prepared statements with such a query to guard against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Your query might be faster if you fetch one row at a time rather than using fetch all. As you have written it, it has to get all rows before even beginning to write out the options.

Comment: @SimonGoater thanks for your response but it is the client's requirement to show all the records in a dropdown and then he may be able to filter those records by typing in the desired value